# How do I bind a volume in Windows docker?

Tags: windows, docker

I'm running Windows 2019 Server with latest docker.

I need to start a windows container, and bind the current C: to Z: in the container, but this does not work:

```
docker run -v c:\:z:\ -it XXX cmd.exe
```

What's the correct syntax?

**EDIT**

Here's what I've tried

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker run --mount 'type="bind",source="C:\",target="Z:\"' -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809 cmd.exe
invalid argument "type=bind,source=C:\",target=Z:\"" for "--mount" flag: parse error on line 1, column 19: bare " in non-quoted-field
See 'docker run --help'.
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker run --mount type=bind,source=C:\,target=Z:\ -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809 cmd.exe
docker: Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 9b4e6759c82a071453bf4449f18dbbb2bd90511651c146a6e561a45771e0548c: The parameter is incorrect.
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Comment: You are using powershelgl or cmd?

Comment: @HamzaAnis cmd, I can switch to powershell if there's a solution to it

Comment: Yes if that solves the problem because I am seeing you are using `\` instead of `/`. Maybe also try `docker run -v c:/:z:/ -it XXX cmd.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with [mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag) syntax?

using Powershell:

```
docker run --mount 'type="bind",source="C:\",target="Z:\"' myimage:latest
```

or

Without quotes:

```
docker run --mount type=bind,source=C:\,target=Z:\ myimage:latest
```

Comment: invalid argument "'type=bind,source=C:\",target=Z:\"'" for "--mount" flag: parse error on line 1, column 20: bare " in non-quoted-field

Comment: If I stripe the quotes: `invalid argument "'type=bind,source=C:\\,target=Z:\\'" for "--mount" flag: unexpected key ''type' in ''type=bind'`

Comment: are you using `PowerShell`? the invalid argument seems like a `cmd` issue. I've updated my answer to highlight it

Comment: In powershell I got `invalid argument "type=bind,source=C:\",target=Z:\"" for "--mount" flag: parse error on line 1, column 19: bare " in non-quoted-field`

Comment: I've added a without quotes variation. Could you try it?

Comment: Without quotes I got `docker: Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 9b4e6759c82a071453bf4449f18dbbb2bd90511651c146a6e561a45771e0548c: The parameter is incorrect.`

Comment: Edited question

Comment: Is this error happening just when you try to use a different driver like `Z`? Does it work with `--mount type=bind,source=C:\tmp,target=C:\tmp`? I'm asking because of [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/42159)

Comment: This also works `docker run -v c:\:c:\tmp -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809 cmd.exe`

Comment: might be a problem with the driver, do you have something in the Event Viewer?

Answer (score 1):

I just got this to work:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v //e/testdata/:/opt/testdata imagetag
```

On host windows:  `e:\testdata`

mapped in container:   `/opt/testdata`

To access `e:\testdata` one needs to put a double slash before the drive letter, and no colon there.  I am mapping into a linux container so that is a normal unix style path.  The software inside the container was able to read and write the windows files.